# AppleScript enter a keystroke as soon as a window opens

Tags: applescript, shortcuts-app

I would like to enter a keystroke {return} as soon as a window opens.
Currently I set a delay for 20s and then keystroke {return}.
But the opening time of the application varies from 10-25 sec.
So I would like to keystroke {return} as soon as the application opens.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Applescript has the capacity to respond to things like this, but to answer effectively, we'd need much more detail. What's the app, what's showing while it is loading, what's the window that eventually appears, what does return do, etc. Can you edit the question with more info?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using `repeat until window "window_name" of process "application_name" exists`